# tinymce does not load if upon loading the page I immediately click on the textfield

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using the `tinymce-rails` gem in my Rails 4.2 app.

**Problem:** When loading a page with a tinymce textfield, if I immediately quickly click on that textfield (before the page has had a chance to load tinymce) then tinymce won't load. The textfield will then just be a regular textfield. So there seems to be a timing issue of some sorts going on.

The problem particularly exists on my (somewhat slow) development server and if the textfield has a lot of text in it. But also on my faster production server and when there's less text in the textfield, the problem is replicable (just have to click faster).

Is there a solution around this? It is not possible to replicate the problem with the demo on the tinymce website, so it must have to do something with my implementation.

---

My view/form:

```
<%= tinymce_assets %> 
...Some text...
<%= form_for(@helptext, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, maxlength: 250, class: 'form-control input-md', rows: 2 %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, required: true, class: "form-control input-md tinymce", rows: 10, cols: 120 %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

In addition, I of couse have `gem 'tinymce-rails'` in my Gemfile, and I've customized `config/tinymce.yml` to load with the menu I'd like.

Comment: I don't think it's a rails problem. Try to isolate it with a simple page, no additional javascript, just required tinymce and see if this still happens. If so, then you should look for bug reports in tinymce, probably someone spotted it already